# Return value based on interpolation of a set of 3d data points in R

Tags: r, 3d

I have a set of 3D data (x, y, z), where `x` and `y` represent coordinates of some points within a 2D model and `z` is the temperature at these points.

I need help to do the following:

1. carry out 3D interpolation and draw contours within a specified area
   i.e within the model boundaries. The data are provided below.
2. based on the above interpolation, return the z value of a given
   point e.g. x =8.55 and y = 3.25 coordinates.

The x, y, z data is provided in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj8knbidq1w8hw8/CPTdata.csv?dl=0) file [click the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj8knbidq1w8hw8/CPTdata.csv?dl=0).

x1, y1: the coordinates of the specified area (the model boundries):

```
x1= c(-5,-5, 0, 18, 25, 25, -5)
y1= c(-5, 0,  0, 10.5, 10.5,-5, -5)
```

thanks
Oli

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What have you already tried that didn't work ?

Comment: It was ok to draw contours within a uniform rectangular grids, however drawing these contours within the specified area (defined by x1 and y1 shown above) was not successful.